# Setting lsp-dart indentation

Tags: dart, emacs, indentation

The [Flutter/Dart project](https://flutter.dev/)
[recommends](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor?tab=emacs)
using the [lsp-dart](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-dart) package.

I'm quite partial to an indentation of 4 spaces. What's the appropriate way to set it in `~/.emacs`?

Curiously, [flutter format](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/formatting)  itself doesn't offer such an option, making for a rather heavy-handed set of tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flutter format` uses the heavily road-tested values from the home office. And yes, it's highly opinionated, and ensures whitespace or rewrapping doesn't needlessly occur when editing someone else's code and submitting a pull request. Considering the hoarde of people working on Dart at Google, this is a wise choice.